# How to secure an IoT device

Tags: disk-encryption, ubuntu, iot

Which is the proper way to prevent users to read sensible information stored inside an IoT device (e.g. source code / private keys...)?

Fully disk encryption is of course an option, but is it possible to boot the device without asking the user for a password?

How do operating systems like Ubuntu Core handle these security aspects?

Comment: most iot devs don't have disks. they also don't have source code.

Comment: @dandavis I was probably not clear enough. I'm referring to a device with an operating system (e.g. a raspberry Pi with a sd card) and a source code that does something (e.g. turn on/off some lights in the house when some conditions are met)

Comment: That's a very liberal use of the term "IoT". You're just talking about a headless, unattended computer ...